Error (Xcode): 'SpeechToTextPlugin' has different definitions in different modules;
I upgraded my Mac to Sequoia and XCode 16 yesterday and ever since cannot build my Flutter app anymore. I got a bunch of error messages which led me to upgrade all my packages, re-install cocoa pods etc. Error messages have since changed and I'm left with this:
Error (Xcode): 'SpeechToTextPlugin' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is definition in module 'speech_to_text.Swift' found method
/Users/username/StudioProjects/projectname/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/speech_to_text/speech_to_text.framework/Headers/speech_to_text-Swift.h:666:0

Modules Issue (Xcode): Definition of 'SpeechToTextPlugin' must be imported from module 'speech_to_text.Swift' before it is required
/Users/username/StudioProjects/projectname/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:131:3

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 mini.

I have since tried to uninstall, disintegrate and reinstall cocoapods several times with repo upgrade etc. I have also set my platform to ios 16. I have also set the configuration like so (because several ppl suggested changing these):

although I'm not quite sure what exactly this all means.


Try deleting build directory from root of the project and folder Pods from ios directory
Then open ios directory via terminal and enter arch -x86_64 pod update command
Try running app

P.S. Worked for me.
